# How can I share code between my projects?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have some code which I want to re-use in my other Phoenix/Elixir projects but which I don't want to upload to hex.pm and distribute via Internet.  How can I share it among different projects I have except the most straightforward approach by copy-pasting code into each of my projects?

Comment: `mix` has an ability to download the code from github instead of hex.pm  +private repos.

Comment: The rules of this site state to use English in questions/comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As clearly stated in [`Mix.Tasks.Deps`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html) documentation, `mix` supports two types of dependencies besides `hex.pm`:

> Mix also supports Git and path dependencies:
>
> ```
> {:foobar, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git", tag: "0.1"}
> {:foobar, path: "path/to/foobar"}
> ```

[Path options](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html#module-path-options-path) are:

```
:path        — the path for the dependency
:in_umbrella — when true, sets a path dependency pointing 
               to `“../#{app}”`, sharing the same environment 
               as the current application
```

The latter is probably out of your interest, unless you create an umbrella project. The former would be used as:

```
{:my_shared_hex_package, path: "../shared/my_shared_hex_package"}
```

or like, depending on your actual path.

Another possible option would be to create a private git[hub] repo and use it to share common private code across projects. That way you’ll be able to still go through the release pipeline (e.g. continuous integration, hot-swap deploys etc) without opening your private code.

Comment: I'd think the quality of this answer could improve further by stressing that git will work with private repositories (I think that this is currently the method used in the vast majority of cases where you don't want to share code through Hex.pm).

Comment: @cdegroot thanks for the tip, updated. In fact, that was my very first suggestion (see comments to the OP,) but afterwards I realized the goal of this particular question was to do things offline.